# Trigger para crear shema postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, trigger, multitenant

Estoy trabajando con postgres y necesito programar un disparador que cree un nuevo Shemá para cada usuario que se registre después de insertar datos en la tabla de usuarios.

El desencadenador debe tomar de la tabla de usuarios el valor de la columna nick y nombrar el esquema que se va a crear.

Ejemplo de lo que trato de hacer: el usuario se registra con el apodo "jon doe" y después del registro activa la función dese PHP o trigger que crea el Shemá con el nombre: jon_doe.

Comment: Bienvenida/o a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Las preguntas muy amplias y/o basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). Procura delimitar tu pregunta a un problema _específico_.

Comment: dame una buena explicacion (pero buena buena) de porque cada usuario que creas deberia tener un schema de db diferente... eso no suena nada logico

Comment: Para que cada usuario tenga su propio espacio en una misma DB y aisle su informacion de los demas usuarios. No es la logica de una aplicacion multitenat?